# SoapServer->handle() ignoring output buffering

Tags: php, soap, buffering, output-buffering, soapserver

I am attempting to capture the response sent by PHP's `SoapServer` class for debugging before it is actually sent to the browser.

I am utilising `Zend_Soap_Server` which is supposed to allow the capture of the output from `SoapServer->handle()` using output buffering. However, the handle method seems to be completely ignoring the buffer, sending directly to the browser and killing the request.

This is an extract taken directly from the `Zend_Soap_Server->handle()` method.

```
ob_start();
if ($setRequestException instanceof Exception) {
    // Create SOAP fault message if we've caught a request exception
    $fault = $this->fault($setRequestException->getMessage(), 'Sender');
} else {
    try {
        $soap->handle($this->_request);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $fault = $this->fault($e);
    }
}
$this->_response = ob_get_clean();
```

As you can see from above, the output from `$soap->handle()` should be captured in the buffer and assigned to `$this->_response` with `ob_get_clean()`. PHP never seems to get to this point though as `$soap->handle()` is ending the request.

If I echo a string within the buffer, it is not sent to the browser and is buffered correctly which makes me think that `$soap->handle()` is doing something that breaks it.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that PHP was throwing a fatal within the handle method due to a request namespacing issue (could not find a procedure method).

When a fatal occurs within the SOAP response compilation process, it is formatted as a SOAP response and sent to the browser before the process is halted which means that any output will escape the buffer.

I hope this helps anyone that stumbles across this in the future.